# Entity join yields no results - generated SQL does

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am having a bit of trouble with the following code in LINQ / EF-Core.

The query itself is simple enough, and I am not sure why it isn't working?

The SQL behind has returned a value, but EF is yielding no results.

The following is my failed attempts, and idea why it is not working?

First attmept

```
                    var test = (from pages in _dbContext.Pages
                    from claims in _dbContext.AspNetUserClaims
                    where claims.UserId == data.UserId
                    where pages.PermissionValue == claims.ClaimType
                    select new
                    {
                        pages.PermissionValue,
                        claims.UserId
                    }).ToList();
```

Second attempt

```
                    var result = _dbContext.Pages.GroupJoin(_dbContext.AspNetUserClaims, p => p.PermissionValue,
                    c => c.ClaimType, (p, g) => new {Parent = p, Children = g});
```

The SQL the first one generates (which returns a value) is

```
    SELECT [pages].[PermissionValue], [claims].[UserId]
    FROM [AspNetPages] AS [pages]
    CROSS JOIN [dbo].[AspNetUserClaims] AS [claims]
    WHERE ([claims].[UserId] = 'omitted') AND (([pages].[PermissionValue] = 
    [claims].[ClaimType]) OR 
    ([pages].[PermissionValue] IS NULL AND [claims].[ClaimType] IS NULL))
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please specify the exact EF Core version.

Comment: What is the value of `test.Count`?

Comment: @IvanStoev - EF Core -  2.02

mjwills - Count returns 0 (the compiled sql returns 1)

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce.

Comment: Are you possibly pointing to the wrong database?

Comment: Hey @mjwills - pointing to the correct database.

Comment: What do you mean by `the compiled sql`?

Comment: Sorry, bad choice of words. Generated. The SQL that is generated by EF.

Comment: What is the actual value of `omitted`?

Comment: A userId string, for example "c515b8eb-a58f-5716-8d93-c8ccd534f9cd"